# Packing a 16-bit floating point variable into two 8-bit variables (aka half into two bytes)

Tags: xna, bit, hlsl, shift, pack

I code on XNA and only has access to shader model 3, hence no bitshift operators. I need to pack two random 16-bit floating point variables (meaning NOT in range [0,1] but ANY RANDOM FLOAT VARIABLE) into two 8-bit variables. There is no way to normalize them.

I thought about doing bitshifting manually but I can't find a good article on how to convert a random decimal float (not [0,1]) into binary and back.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good idea - a 16-bit float already has very limited range and precision. Remember that 8-bits leaves you with just 256 possible values!

Getting an 8-bit value into a shader is trivial. As a colour is one method. You can use each channel as a normalised range, from 0 to 1.

Of course, you say you don't want to normalise your values. So I assume you want to maintain the nice floating-point property of a wide range with better precision closer to zero.

(Now would be a good time to read some background info on [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point). Especially about [half-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) and [minifloats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat) [and microfloats](http://www.mrob.com/pub/math/floatformats.html#minifloat).)

One way to do that would be to encode your values using a [logarithm and an exponent](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponents-logarithms.html) (to encode and decode, respectivly). This is basically exactly what the floating-point format itself does. The exact maths will depend on the precision and the range that you desire - (which 256 values will you represent?) - so I will leave it as an exercise.

Comment: To be honest I have almost made it with division and modulo (%). High byte is value/256 and low is value%256. The decoding is simply High*256+Low. It works in mah excel sheet but it does not work in the program :). I guess it is one of the two things:

a) because I get my value as a float instead of half and

b) because my values can be negative.